# How do you escape percent signs when making a HTTP web query to CartoDB

Tags: html, postgresql, cartodb

For example:

something like this works:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE field_1 LIKE 'FOO_'
```

However this does not:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE field_1 LIKE 'FOO%'
```

I've tried every escape sequence I can find. Tt either doesn't work or the HTML query interprets the % prior to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your query in the `encodeURIComponent` function

```js
let query = encodeURIComponent(
  "select admin from public.ne_adm0_europe where admin like 'Ger%'"
)

let url = `https://cartojs-test.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=${query}`

fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((myJson) => console.log(myJson));
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE field_1 LIKE 'FOO%25'